# Heroku web python app with java packages: how to set the Procfile

Tags: java, python, heroku, procfile, tabula

I worked for a project that consisted of a web python app which I would like to deploy with Heroku. I can use Python but I've never used Java.

I already succeeded in deploying but when I wanted to use it I got an error like: "Java not found" and that's because in the python script it is present a package called `tabula-py` which is based in Java.

After some arrangements I created a "pom.xml" file and I almost basically copied the code from here: https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/blob/master/pom.xml

Now, I can succeed in deploying the new version but I have an application error (`desc=No web processes running`). I discovered that I miss a Procfile, but I from google I can't get what to write in it. I tried this for now:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* technology.tabula.appname
```

Performing `heroku local web` in the terminal I get:

```
17:18:19 web.1   |  Error: Could not find or load main class technology.tabula.appname
17:18:19 web.1   |  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: technology.tabula.appname
```

"technology.tabula" corresponds to the groupID tag contained in pom.xml.

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Could not find or load main class` This means that the Java interpreter (the JVM) found *something,* but it couldn't locate the class you indicated you want to start with.  This class: `technology.tabula.appname` is missing.  Why I cannot say, you'll need to check your Java deployment and give us more details.  Possibly you deployed the wrong file or put it in a location that Python isn't looking at.

Comment: @markspace maybe I say something wrong. Actually I didn't do any Java deployment. I just create "system.properties", "pom.xml" and "Procfile". In my ignorance they are requested in order to allow the tabula-py package to work.

Comment: I don't know anything about Heroku and almost as little about Python, sorry can't help you with the specifics of your deployment.